# How to clear material-table filter values or force re-render of component on react-router navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

I have a project where I'm using react and react-router-dom to create my project and I'm using material-table to display some data in a table component. I have enabled filtering in the MaterialTable component and I'm having an issue where navigating away from the page with the table doesn't clear out the users filter input.

Currently, if a user is on a page that has a material-table and they filter the table data by putting a string in a column's filter field, their entry persists even if they navigate away from that page and then return.

Clearly, it would be better if the text that was entered into the filter field were cleared if the user navigates away from the page with the table and returns.

I saw suggestions of using and mutating a key that gets passed to the MaterialTable component in react. I've tried that, too, but the text entered into the filter field is still not cleared out.

[Here's a codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-table-starter-template-forked-65xlpz?file=/src/index.js) where I've replicated a very simple version of what I'm facing. From the home page, go to the Table, enter something into the filter field to filter the results. Click back to the home page and then back to the table page and the filter will still be populated with the previously entered filter value.

Clicking the 'reset' button will increment the tableKey that is passed to the table in an attempt to get it to remount the MaterialTable, but there's no effect.

Anyone else run into this or have a solution/suggestion?

Comment: Well, that's strange. Updating a prop that gets passed to a child component should trigger a refresh. Perhaps some sort of quirk/feature of MaterialTable not clearing filter values?

Comment: The bedrock of this question seems to be about getting the `MaterialTable` component to reset/remount when the React key passed to it updates, which has nothing to do with routing. If you resolve this issue then the problem of resetting the table is trivially solved under any condition, i.e. when navigating to `"/table"` and rendering the `TablePage` component. The question should also be focused to a single specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

```
actions={[
          {
            icon: "refresh",
            tooltip: "Refresh Data",
            isFreeAction: true,
            onClick: () =>
              tableRef.current &&
              tableRef.current.dataManager.columns.forEach((item: any) => {
                console.log(item);
                tableRef.current.onFilterChange(item.tableData.id, "");
              }),
          },

]}
```

Also, you can use the below code to remove filter values when the table refreshes.

```
tableRef.current && tableRef.current.onQueryChange({ filters: [] });
```